# How to unpickle objects from .pkl file using python

Tags: python, pickle

I created a student class.I stored every student details in a file.I used serialization concept to store the details.The problem is while unpickling the data it gives first object only.Can anyone say how to retrieve all objects which are in .pkl file

and my code is

this is my code

```
'''
Created on Apr 20, 2015

@author: murali

'''
import pickle
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, roll, sex, subject, total):
        """Return a new Car object."""
        self.name = name
        self.roll = roll
        self.sex = sex
        self.subject = subject
        self.total = total

print ("*************MENU*******************************")
print ("\t 1.Add New Student")
print ("\t 2.Display all Students")
print ("\t 3.Delete Student")
print ("\t 4.Display all Boys")
print ("\t 5.Display all Girls")
print ("\t 6.Display ascending order of marks")
print ("\t 7.Display alphabetical order of names ")
print ("\t 0.exit")
print ("************************************************")

print ("\n Enter your choice")
ch=int(raw_input())

if ch==1:
    print ("Enter Student Details")     
    print ("Enter Student Name")  
    n=raw_input()
    print ("Enter Student Roll number") 
    r=raw_input()
    print ("Male or Female")
    s=raw_input()
    print ("Enter Subject ")
    su=raw_input()
    print ("Enter Student marks ")
    t=raw_input()
    s=Student(n,r,s,su,t);
    with open("save2.pkl",'ab') as outfile:
        pickle.dump(s,outfile)
        print ("Data saved Successfully")
elif ch==2:
    st=[];
    f=open("save2.pkl",'rb')
    storedlist=pickle.load(f)
    print (storedlist)
    #st.append(storedlist)
    print ("Students are-")
    print (storedlist)
    #for i in storedlist:
    print(storedlist.name)
    print(storedlist.roll)
    print(storedlist.sex)
    print(storedlist.subject)
    print(storedlist.total)
    f.close();
    #s1=None
    #with open("save2.pkl",'rb') as infile:
        #s1=pickle.load(infile)
        #print (s1.name)
        #print (s1.roll)
        #print (s1.sex)
        #print (s1.subject)
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here?

Comment: Can you show us what code you used to create the .pkl and what you're trying to use to unpickle it?

Comment: How do you know you only have the first object? How do you know you pickled more than one?

Comment: with open("save2.pkl",'ab') as outfile:
        pickle.dump(s,outfile)

Comment: @MuraliKrishna also, it would be helpful if you could provide a sample data structure of what you're pickling. Might be best if you edit the question.

Comment: You pickle one `Student` object. You can't append to a pickle file and expect to get all the objects back. It is a binary format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't appending binary pickles work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857970/why-doesnt-appending-binary-pickles-work)

Comment: Thank you peter.But in which format I have to store these details.

Comment: @PeterWood I need to retrieve all the students details which are stored in that file...

Comment: See the answer to the linked question. You need to keep retrieving until you get an `EOF` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is that `pickle.load` only reads one item from your pkl file. That's just how its designed. If you have more than one item in the same file, you'll need to repeatedly load them until you get an `EOFError` when there is nothing more to read. Something like:

```
students = []
try:
    with open("save2.pkl",'rb') as f:
        while True:                          # loop indefinitely
            students.append(pickle.load(f))  # add each item from the file to a list
except EOFError:                             # the exception is used to break the loop
    pass                                     # we don't need to do anything special
```

Alternatively, you could maintain in memory a complete list of the items your file is intended to contain (e.g. all the `Student` instances). When the list is modified, you'd pickle the whole list and write it all out together in one call to `pickle.dump`, overwriting the previous contents of the your data file. Rather than reading the data when the user requested it, you'd read it at the start of the program, and already have it in memory if the user wants it later.

This is a bit harder to show, as I don't want to rewrite large chunks of your code. I think these snippets are all you need:

Just below definition of the Student class:

```
try:
    with open("save2.pkl",'rb') as f:
        students = pickle.load(f)     # just one call, loads the whole list
except FileNotFoundError:             # if the file doesn't exist, make an empty list
    students = []
```

Where you are currently appending to the file:

```
s=Student(n,r,s,su,t)
students.append(s)                        # update the in-memory list of students
with open("save2.pkl",'wb') as outfile:   # use mode "w" to overwrite existing file
    pickle.dump(students, outfile)        # dump the whole list, not only s
    print ("Data saved Successfully")
```

In the later code you wouldn't need to re-read the file. It can just use the `students` list you already have in memory.

This second approach is not terribly useful given your current menu design which can only be passed through a single time. But if you later put the menu in a loop (as the `0` option suggests you eventually will want to do), you might appreciate not needing to read the data file over and over.

This approach is also much better than the other version if you ever extend your `Student` type to have references to other `Student` instances (perhaps you're recording lab partners, or teams for some group project). If you pickle such interconnected objects separately, the links between them will not be retained when you load them again. The loaded versions will still have references, but the references will be to copies of the other `Student` instances, not the same ones you'll get when the other `Student`s are loaded themselves. If you dump and load a whole list of `Student`s at once, however, their interconnections will be maintained. (This is fairly deep stuff, don't worry too much if you don't understand what I'm talking about.)