# Appending Pickle Files in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I have 100 dataframes (formatted exactly the same) saved on my disk as 100 pickle files. These dataframes are each roughly 250,000 rows long. I want to save all 100 dataframes in 1 dataframe which I want to save on my disk as 1 pickle file.

This is what I am doing so far:

```
path = '/Users/srayan/Desktop/MyData/Pickle'
df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pkl')):
    newDF = pd.read_pickle(filename)
    df = df.append(newDF)
df.to_pickle("/Users/srayan/Desktop/MyData/Pickle/MergedPickle.pkl")
```

I understand that pickle serializes the data frame but is it necessary for me to take my pickle file, unserialize it, append the data frame, and then serialize it again? Or is there a faster way to do this? With all the data I have, I am getting slowed down

Comment: hope the link will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857970/why-doesnt-appending-binary-pickles-work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` with appending each `df` to `list` and only once [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
files = glob.glob('files/*.pkl')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(fp) for fp in files], ignore_index=True)
```

what is same as:

```
dfs = []
for filename in glob.glob('files/*.pkl'):
    newDF = pd.read_pickle(filename)
    dfs.append(newDF)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more compact version in one line:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_pickle, glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pkl'))))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.